# How do I use find and execute a command for each file in Bash shell?

Tags: shell, busybox

I tried the following, which normally works in Bash:

```
root@nycmesh-eb94:/etc# find .  -exec grep eth0 {}\;
find: -exec requires an argument
root@nycmesh-eb94:/etc# find .  -exec 'grep eth0 {};'
find: -exec requires an argument
root@nycmesh-eb94:/etc# echo $SHELL
/bin/ash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon is necessary for `find` to work out where to stop reading the command line for `-exec`.  The slash is necessary to stop `ash` interpreting the semicolon as a command divider.  In your first example, there's a space missing before it, so `find` treats the semicolon as part of the same parameter as `{}`.

Your second example won't work, because the semicolon is treated as part of the parameter to `-exec` as it is inside the quote marks. Also, the quotes would make `-exec` try to execute a program called "`grep eth0 myfile.ext`", treating the whole phrase as a single parameter.  The following should work:

```
# find . -exec grep eth0 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this particular issue, but it's not quite the same. You can't limit the search to a filename pattern, so it searches junk files like binaries.

```
# find . -name \*.sh -exec grep nycmesh_configure {}\;
find: -exec requires an argument
# grep -r nycmesh_configure * 2>/dev/null
```